# netctl start PROFILE fails

Tags: wifi, netctl, arch-arm

Upon login to serial console I run a command via `/etc/profile`
`netctl start wlan0-ROUTENZUG`
However it fails, yielding this output

`Job for netctl@wlan0\x2ROUTENZUG.service failed. See ´sytemctl status netctl@wlan0\x2ROUTENZUG.service´ and ´journalctl -xn for details.´`

The latter contains nothing about that job, the first just tells me the job is dead.
I just tested: The command fails as well when given manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, figured it out:
Problem was, I already had brought the respective interface up
`ifconfig wlan0 up`
which prevents the job from working.
Info was obtained by running
`netctl status wlan0-ROUTENZUG`